# AWS EventBridge Rule Ignoring Key Prefix & Suffix Matching

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I have an Event Bridge rule created where when I drop a file into an S3 bucket it will trigger a Step function.

I only want to trigger this rule when:

- A file is in a folder called `files/` (`prefix: "files/"`)
- The file is a CSV (`suffix: ".csv"`)

However this rule is being triggered for any files regardless of their suffix and prefix. For instance I dropped a .pdf file in and it triggered the step function.

```json
    {
      "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
      "source": ["aws.s3"],
      "detail": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": ["my-files-bucket"]
        },
        "object": {,
          "key": [{
            "prefix": "files/"
          }, {
            "suffix": ".csv"
          }]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a workaround? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75368917/apply-several-eventbridge-patterns-on-the-same-field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.  EventBridge treats multiple values in brackets as an [OR condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html#eb-filtering-match-values).  Events will match your pattern if the object key begins with `files/` OR ends with `.csv`.

As far as I know, it's not possible to apply an AND condition to a single field.

Comment: Yeah, I've come to that conclusion & figuring a work around. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: @bananabreadbob did you end up figuring out a solution ?

Comment: I moved the suffix check into the codebase.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround to this. EventBridge now supports wildcards for key matching: [Filtering events in Amazon EventBridge with wildcard pattern matching](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/filtering-events-in-amazon-eventbridge-with-wildcard-pattern-matching/)

Here is an example of solution (this also shows a scenario where you want to match multiple file types):

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["my-files-bucket"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "wildcard": "files/*.csv"
      }, {
        "wildcard": "files/*.pdf"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```