# Apply several EventBridge patterns on the same field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

EventBridge bus receives events from S3 bucket.
I need to create a rule that only handles S3 events from objects with Key **prefix** `dir/sub-dir/` and **suffix** `.pdf`.

Tried the rule below, but it is handled as `OR` statement:

```
    new events.Rule(this, 'MyRule', {
      eventPattern: {
        source: ['aws.s3'],
        detailType: ['Object Created'],
        detail: {
          object: {
            key: [
              { prefix: 'dir/sub-dir/' },
              {
                suffix: '.pdf',
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to my answer in another post:
[AWS EventBridge Rule Ignoring Key Prefix & Suffix Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77478054/12191995)

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["my-files-bucket"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "wildcard": "files/*.csv"
      }, {
        "wildcard": "files/*.pdf"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make it work, but I hope there is a better answer:

```
    new events.Rule(this, 'MyRule', {
      eventPattern: {
        source: ['aws.s3'],
        detailType: ['Object Created'],
        detail: {
          object: {
            key: [
              { prefix: 'dir/sub-dir/' },
              $or: [{ key: [{ suffix: '.pdf' }] }, { fieldThatDoesntExist: ['its a hack'] }],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work - I get an InvalidEventPatternException. Did you have any luck with a better solution?

Comment: What you have essentially done here is repeated the "key" key.  So any object in any folder that ends ".pdf" will match.  As on duplicate keys, it will obey the last one.  Curious if those are the results you are seeing as well.